# WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object in angular storybook

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, storybook

WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object.
Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
I am getting this error when setting up storybook to angular , Would like to have suggestions

Comment: share your webpack config

Comment: using the webpack5 version on angular cli and getting the issue